# $\mathbb{Q}^*$ closed in the finite ideles?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I want to consider the (topological) group of 'finite' ideles: If

$$\mathbb{A}_\text{fin} = \widehat{\prod}^{\mathbf{Z}_p}_p \mathbf{Q}_p$$

(the 'hat' indicates the so-called restricted product topology)
then

$$\mathbb{I}_\text{fin} := \mathbb{A}_\text{fin}^\times$$

The topology is such that it becomes homeomorphic to (i.e. we can also take this as a definition)

$$\mathbb{I}_\text{fin} = \widehat{\prod}^{\mathbf{Z}_p^\times}_p \mathbf{Q}_p^\times$$

My question:

What is the closure of $\mathbb{Q}^\times$ which is considered to be diagonally embedded into $\mathbb{I}_\text{fin}$?

I know already that it is not whole $\mathbb{I}_\text{fin}$ as a direct computation shows that there is no $q \in \mathbb{Q}^\times$ in the neighborhood

$$ U_{1/2}(2) \times U_{1/3}(1) \times \prod_{p \geq 5} \mathbf{Z}_p^\times$$
of the element
$$(2,1,1,1,1,...)$$
Thanks in advance,

FW

Comment: Just checking that I understand the topology: why isn't $q=10$ in that neighborhood of $(2,1,1,\ldots)$? $10=2+8$, $10=1+9$.

Comment: Oops, I missed the part about it having to be a $p$-adic unit for all $p>3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{Q}^\times \cap \prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p^\times = \{\pm 1\}$. In particular, $(\prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p^\times) \setminus \{-1\}$ is an open neighbourhood of $1$ which meets $\mathbb{Q}^\times$ only at $1$. This shows that $\mathbb{Q}^\times$ is discrete in $\mathbb{A}_\text{fin}^\times$.

Comment: Ah ok, and then, since $\mathbb{A}_\text{fin}$ is an LCH group, $\mathbb{Q}^\times$ is automatically closed by groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Discrete_subgroup_implies_closed (and the construction of the symmetric square root can be found here: math.uh.edu/~vern/grouprepn.pdf, prop. 5.7). Weird. Thanks a lot!!